# ¿Cómo escapar correctamente comando bash a través de ssh?

Tags: bash, shell

Para ejecutar un comando en una máquina remota a través de ssh utilizo:

```
ssh usuario@servidor "/home/ubuntu/bin/ejecutarComando.sh"
```

o

```
ssh usuario@servidor '/home/ubuntu/bin/ejecutarComando.sh'
```

Véase la diferencia entre comillas simples y comillas dobles. Si el comando a a ejecutar remotamente precisa de comillas simples utilizo las dobles y viceversa.

¿Cómo hago para escapar correctamente las comillas en caso de que el comando a ejecutar remotamente tenga ambos tipos de comillas como el siguiente ejemplo?

```
awk '/a/ {print $4 "\t" $3}' /home/ubuntu/listado.txt
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para proveer la respuesta en español:

"Si de verdad quieres usar comillas simples en la capa mas externa, recuerda que puedes pegar las dos tipos de comillas. Por ejemplo:

```
 alias rxvt='urxvt -fg '"'"'#111111'"'"' -bg '"'"'#111111'"'"
 #                     ^^^^^       ^^^^^     ^^^^^       ^^^^
 #                     12345       12345     12345       1234
```

"Explanación de como `'"'"'` es interpretado simplemente como `'`:

1. `'` Termina la primera cita que usa comillas simples.
2. `"` Empieza la segunda cita que usa comillas dobles.
3. `'` carácter citado.
4. `"` Termina la segunda cita, usando comillas dobles.
5. `'` Empieza la tercera cita, usando comillas simples.

Si no dejas espacio blanco entre (1) y (2), o entre (4) y (5), el shell va a interpretar ese string como una palabra larga."

El crédito se debe a esta respuesta de StackOverflow en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250279/6252597 y @lois6b por compartirla.

Comment: gracias por explicarlo. no tenia tiempo de convertirlo en respuesta

Comment: Responde perfectamente a mi duda. Genial, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente tienes que colocar el comando a realizar entre comillas, la shell ya se encarga de sintetizarlo.

```
ssh servidor "awk '/a/ {print $4 "\t" $3}' /home/ubuntu/listado.txt"
```